# Set maximum Date in DatePicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I want to set the maximum Date to present Date. Also I Want to let the user to select date between 100 years range. 
For example:
I want to let the users to select year between (2014-1914) range. i.e. only 100 years range. So user will able to select only the dates between this range. I did this writing this code:

```
dialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-100 * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60
    * 60 * 1000);
```

And it works. it lets the user to select the dates between 100 years range(2014-1914). But problem is, If subtract `System.currentTimeMillis()` with

```
100 * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60* 60 * 1000,
```

When I select the dialog, instead of displaying the current date, it displays sep 02 2014. What can I do to set the 100 year range.?
Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
100 * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60* 60 * 1000
```

This expression is computed with 32-bit `int` precision but the value is much too large to fit in 32 bits. To compute with 64-bit `long`, make one of the factors a `long` with `L`, e.g.

```
100L * 12 * 30 * 24 * 60* 60 * 1000
```

However, consider using `Calendar` for datetime math like this. For example,

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -100);
long hundredYearsAgo = c.getTimeInMillis();
```

and then set `hundredYearsAgo` as the `minDate` and current time as `maxDate`.

Comment: Your asking me to skip first method & use second one?

Comment: Use the latter. The first is just pointing out why the computation didn't work.

Comment: It will set the current date as 1914. I want to let the users to scroll in the range between 100 years. and to display current date when scrolled

Answer (score 0):

use Calendar class to set Max and min date range in DataPicker.
Example code.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
c.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
c.set(Calendar.MONTH, Calendar.JANUARY);
c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);

//set Max date
picker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(c.getTimeInMillis());

//Set Min date
picker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(c.getTimeInMillis());
```